# Image changing div position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two columns separated by or inside a circle page the second column should have an image it like this :

```
<div class="step second">
  <div id="upload-img"></div>
  <div id="sperator">
    <div class="circle" id="or"><p class="number" style="padding-left:25%;">or</div>
  </div>
  <div id="default-img">
    <img src=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason the position of the #sperator div is changing with the image my css is bit long so here is a js fiddle for more explaining : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9wnepxh/)

As you can see the image should be in the same line with the other div but its changing the position of the separator div

Comment: You closed your `<p>` tag with a `</div>` tag. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o9wnepxh/1/)

Comment: Same problem even after changing

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know what you want to achieve. Are you hoping that the separator will operate as a block with width forced between the two columns? I think as you are using absolute positioning your elements are taken out of the flow of the document and sit on top of each other.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @user297904 I also have no idea what your trying to do. But look at the demo I put there... the image is sitting next to the line with the circle.

Comment: I think Ruddy is on the right line, however if you place an image in the first div too, the number circle needs aligning a bit. Maybe this circle should be absolute, so that the two images can be right up alongside each other?

Comment: This is how I would have done it. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g578nbhu/1/)

Comment: Can you do a quick graphical mockup of what you *want* it to look like so we can see what it should look like?

Comment: Just thinking like @Ruddy to get it done: absolute positioning the splitter and floating both columns with a clearfix on the container.

Comment: @Ruddy thats exactly what i tended to do but is there any way to make it responsive ?

Comment: @Ruddy In the first demo what did you changed exactly ?

Comment: @user297904 You can just use percentages for the height and widths.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-check your html tags. Make sure each tag closed correctly

Here your css :

```
.step{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#upload-img{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
    height:100%
}

#default-img{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
    height:100%
    }
#upload-img img, #default-img img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;    
}

#sperator .circle{
    position:absolute;
    height:66px;
    width:66px;
    background-color:black;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-33px auto auto -33px;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;
}
#sperator .circle p{
  font-size:35px;
  font-family:futura-book;
  color:white;    
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0;
  line-height:60px;
}
.step::after{
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    width:3px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-2px;    
    z-index:90;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
}
```

`potition:relative` will be an area that will "lock" every `potition:absolute` inside it.

You can use `position:relative` as parent `div` and `position:absolute` as child `div`.